# How to create different kind of scheduled apex jobs

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, salesforcedx-cli, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

How to create the following apex jobs(Types)

- Reporting Notification
- Sitemap SEO Generation Job
- Sitemap SEO Incremental Job

Can you explain these apex job types and how to create these jobs in salesforce org?

I already know scheduled apex job type. but I'm not familiar with the other apex job types. so my requirement is to create the following jobs in different user account and I don't know how to do that

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a search for each of these three types, you'll find that "Reporting Notification" jobs are created when a user schedules a report, and the other two are created when a Digital Experience is published; these are the jobs used to index the contents so that its accessible to Google and other search engines.